# jquery to resize text based on element div size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a certain issue where I need to auto resize text depending on how many elements are inside the parent.  I've tried a few libraries like BigText and FitText but they don't seem to work.

```
<div class="prize-cont">
    <div class="prize">
        <h2>$1000</h2>
        <span>Youth Grand Prize</span>
    </div>
    <div class="prize">
        <h2>$1000</h2>
        <span>Adult Grand Prize</span>
    </div>
    <div class="prize">
        <h2>$200</h2>
        <span>Finalists</span>
    </div>
    <div class="prize">
        <h2>T-Shirt</h2>
        <span>Viewer's Choice</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically it is a fixed container height and I need to get the main container height then count how many children there are `.prize` in this case and then get the current font size of the `h2` and `span` and then figure out how many pixels I need to go down on each element in order to prevent overflow.

```
(($) ->
  $.fn.textfill = (maxFontSize) ->
    maxFontSize = parseInt(maxFontSize, 10)
@each ->
  ourText = $(".prize", this)
  parent = ourText.parent()
  maxHeight = parent.height()
  maxWidth = parent.width()
  fontSize = parseInt(ourText.css("fontSize"), 10)
  multiplier = maxWidth / ourText.width()
  newSize = (fontSize * (multiplier - 0.1))
  ourText.css "fontSize", (if (maxFontSize > 0 and newSize > maxFontSize) then maxFontSize else newSize)

) jQuery
```

For instance, if my h2's are 20px and my span are 12px and I have 4 prizes and they all fit into the container but then I add another prize I need to subtract whatever the difference is from all of the elements in order to make all spans 10px and all h2 15px so that they fit in the container.

I've been working on this for a few hours and can't seem to figure it out.  any help at all would be appreciated if they know of a plugin/library that would do this or a simple script

Comment: Please post your attempt. "I've been working on this a few hours" is a common said statement that usually comes with no attempt made.

Comment: Right lol....Well I edited my original, if you have trouble reading coffeescript then let me know and I'll convert it

Comment: Thanks, but could you please edit it into your question, not as a comment?

Comment: What happens when your users have user-set fonts they need to use? What about users who come to the site from a mobile device, or a high-density display (Retina for example)? In my experience, forcing resizing like this tends to work badly for users, cross-platform. It's far better to fix a size of the container and allow for scrolling, or allow your design to accommodate expanding height.

Comment: and then...and then...and then...and then. LOL. Take a breath. You're not talking to a person standing in front of you. Your audience isn't going to walk away if you don't get it all out within 3 minutes.

Comment: I would agree mori.  Unfortunately the client wants this and even though I have pushed back they refuse to accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var containerHeight = $('.prize-cont').height();
    var prizeContainers = $('.prize');
    var prizeNum = prizeContainers.length;

    // The max height of a single prize container
    var heightPerPrize = containerHeight / prizeNum;

    var current;
    var header;
    var span;
    // For each prize container...
    $.each(prizeContainers, function() {
        current = $(this);
        current.height(heightPerPrize);

        // Set header height to a fractional height, here it is 1/3
        header = current.find('h2').height(heightPerPrize / 3);

        // Set span height to a fractional height, here it is 2/3
        span = current.find('span').height((heightPerPrize / 3) * 2)
    });
});
```

Comment: that is close, it changes the height when it should change the font size of the h2 and span.  I think I can modify this to get what I need.  Thanks

Comment: sure, close the question by marking a response as the answer if you're done. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<div class="prize-cont">
    <div class="prize">
        <div>
        <h2>$1000</h2>
        <span>Youth Grand Prize</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prize">
        <div>
        <h2>$1000</h2>
        <span>Adult Grand Prize</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prize">
        <div>
        <h2>$200</h2>
        <span>Finalists</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prize">
        <div>
        <h2>T-Shirt</h2>
        <span>Viewer's Choice</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then use the idea of overflow/height to size the text:

```
$('.prize-cont div').each(function () {
    var container = $(this),
        content = container.find('div'),
        i = 0;
    while (content.height() > container.height() && i < 10) {
        var fontSize = container.css('fontSize'),
            numSize = parseInt(fontSize, 10),
            units = fontSize.split(numSize)[1],
            newSize = numSize - 1;
        container.css('fontSize', newSize + units);
        i++;
    }
});
```

There is a working fiddle here for you to "fiddle" with: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/TZ4NQ/22/

I'm sure there are some problems with this approach, but it might just solve your problem. One thing to note, the small amount of JavaScript depends on using a relative font-size for the contents of the div. I also added a div inside your container div that is allowed to flex. When that height is greater than the container, the content font-size is reduced.

Comment: You can also do this without extra divs. `$('.prize-cont div').each(function () {
   var container = $(this),
       content = container.find('div'),
       i = 0;
    while ((container[0].scrollHeight > container[0].clientHeight) && i < 10) {
        var fontSize = container.css('fontSize'),
            numSize = parseInt(fontSize, 10),
            units = fontSize.split(numSize)[1],
            newSize = numSize - 1;
        container.css('fontSize', newSize + units);
        i++;
    }
});` See the fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/TZ4NQ/